# Shiny Interactive Graph plot showing row names

Tags: r, shiny, interactive

I am using Shiny and ggplot2 for an interactive graph. I also used "plot1_click" to get x and y locations.

```
output$selected <- renderText({
paste0("Value=", input$plot1_click$x, "\n",
       "Names=", input$plot1_click$y)  }) #how to get names???
```

This is part of server code. Here what I want is, instead of printing the "y" coordinates, I want to print the corresponding name written in y-axis. Is there any possible way for it??

Comment: This is a bit of a workaround but assuming the data frame you used to plot contains the x and y coords, can you use something like `"Names=", data$name[data$x == input$plot1_click$x & data$y == input$plot1_click$y ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know clicking points is not supported in `plotOutput`. Click events will only return coordinates of the click location. Those coordinates can however be used to figure out the nearest point.

[This shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-selecting-points.html) from the shiny gallery pages uses the function `shiny::nearPoints` which does exactly that. Here is a minimal example.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"),
    verbatimTextOutput('print')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()})
    output$print = renderPrint({
      nearPoints(
        mtcars,             # the plotting data
        input$plot_click,   # input variable to get the x/y coordinates from
        maxpoints = 1,      # only show the single nearest point 
        threshold = 1000    # basically a search radius. set this big enough 
                            # to show at least one point per click
      )
    })
  }
)
```

The `verbatimTextOutput` shows you the nearest point to the clicked location. Notice that `nearPoints` only works with ggplots like that. But the help page suggests that there is also a way to use this with base graphics.